# Possible rejection of application using Apple Push notifications

Tags: ios

I'm reading [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), and I am curious about point related with push notifications rules.
This is the rule, that confuses me, and especially second part:

> Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user
>   consent, as well as apps that require Push Notifications to function,
>   will be rejected

First part is clear :

> Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user
>   consent...

That means,that alert for registering of push notifications needs to be shown, but what is a meaning of second part :

> ... as well as apps that require Push Notifications to function ...

Is that means,that if I have messaging app, that uses Push Notifications for wake up it will be rejected, because Push notifications are heart of app like this?

Comment: IMO, it means that a messaging app must support user initiated polling. In other words, if the user chooses not to allow push notifications, then the user should still be able to get messages by pushing a button to request any new messages from the server. Kind of like good old-fashioned email where you click the send/receive button to get messages.

Comment: Or a little more generically, if the user says "No" when asked about push notifications then your app should still function - it could be a refresh button as @user3386109 said, or whatever makes sense for your app

Comment: Understand it.Thanks guys.

Comment: Hi i need suggestion regarding push notification. I am doing phonegap for both android and ios. My question is can i set toggle button for enabling the pushnotification?. I mean allow user to switch on/off pushnotifications service. This will violate the rules ?